How to fix "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource" Error on FastAPI and React App
I am building a website to manage recipes. The frontend is React and CSS, the backend is FastAPI and the database is SQLite. The app is pretty simple and works fine when run locally.
I have deployed the frontend to Vercel and the backend to Heroku, and now I receive the following error when I make http requests to my backend: "Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://reciperealm-backend-ff4e853245cd.herokuapp.com/users/?email=fakeemail&password=fakepassword' from origin 'https://reciperealm-three.vercel.app' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource."
The code is available on my public GitHub repository:
https://github.com/WilsonGoins/RecipeRealm.git
The main branch is what should be run locally. There are instructions in the ReadMe folder on how to do that.
The FrontendDeployable and BackendDeployable branches are what are currently deployed.
The frontend code is in various folders which each represent a different page in recipe-realm-app/src directory. The backend code is in the FastAPI and the http functions are in FastAPI/main.py
To reiterate, I do not experience this error when I run the frontend and the backend locally, only on the deployed versions.
I tried everything I can think of. I have installed CORS middleware on the entirety of the FastAPI app, I added the missing header to the frontend where I make the request, I added the missing header as part of the response on the backend, and I tried putting the http request in a try/catch block. None of this worked.
I am a college student and went to 4 different TAs and none of them were able to come up with a solution. I have scoured YouTube, FastAPI documentation, Stack Overflow, Reddit, and anywhere else that could offer me an answer.
Most solutions say to install CORSmiddleware which I have done, but for some reason it is not working.
My only other idea is that it could be an issue with Heroku, but I couldn't find any settings that would cause this.

Instead of linking to a repo, please make your question self-contained. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Further related answers could be found here, here, as well as here, here and here
